# What is the nature of the definition symbol?

Tags: notation, definition, axioms

A question about definitions and also notation, illustrated with a trivial example:

---

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ and

$$a:=2,$$

and

$$b:=1$$

I postulate the the following formula holds

$$2c=6a+4b.$$

---

Now I can conclude that "$c=8$".

Why would I write $c=8$ and not $c:=8$? This expression seems to be a question of the history of the derivation, which the mathematican did, why is this encoded in the notation?

> What is the nature of the definition symbol (it doesn't have to be "$:=$", it could be any addition notation for definition, which live besides "$=$")?
>
> Is a definition symbol reecomended of needed? Would it be the exact same thing if I'd always use "$=$", i.e. in the above example define "$a=2$", "$b=1$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the symbol := is meant to be a form of an "assignment operator," which you might encounter in programming.  This appears to be happening for the symbols $a$ and $b$ above.  In the formula you seem to be asking, "Is 2c = 6a + 4b?"

In C family languages, the equals sign is really an assignment of a quantity to a symbol.  The double-equals sign `==` is the isequalto operator.  If you write this in C

```
a = 2;
b = 1;
```

then

`2*c = 6*a + 4*b`

would evaluate to `false`, were `c` to be holding the value 8.

Comment: So perhaps this question belongs in a programming forum...

Comment: No. Assignment is actually a mathematical operation and symbols are defined all of the time.  CS notions like scope pop up (think of variables of summation) all of the time in mathematics.